# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I am trying to fetch an array from a .net WebService and echo it, but it keeps saying: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" if I use var dump i get this so the array is in the variable. Do i need to do something special to it because it's from a .net webservice??? I have no experince in C#. The first function is working just fine.

object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["string"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "Ivo" [1]=> string(6) "Peter" [2]=> string(5) "Simon" [3]=> string(6) "Michel" } }

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient("http://xavier.monkees.com/XavierService.svc?singleWsdl");
$response = $client->CheckName(array(
                                "name" => "$naam"));


$response_array = $client->GetNames()->GetNamesResult;

echo $response_array[1];
?>
```

Comment: Did you forget the `()`on `->GetNamesResult`?

Comment: It looks like $response_array isn't really an array, so you could use the object syntax instead of the array syntax (`$response_array->string`, assuming the object shown at the top of your code is the result of `var_dump($response_array);`.)

Comment: On a side note, "string" seems like kind of a weird name for an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the dump of your object, it looks like the first subscript is "string"

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["string"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "Ivo" [1]=> string(6) "Peter" [2]=> string(5) "Simon" [3]=> string(6) "Michel" } }
```

Try

```
$response_array = $client->GetNames()->GetNamesResult->string[1];
```

or

```
$response_array = $client->GetNames()->GetNamesResult["string"][1];
```